# __pa returns physical address out of range

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, mmu

Working on the arm core adsp-sc572 (Kernel 4.0), I figured out `__pa` is not working correct.
Allocating a big buffer (e.g.500kB) for DMA using kmalloc gives me a virtual address. When using `__pa()` -> it sometimes returns an address out of the physical address range. e.g. `0x88AB0000`

```
0x87FFFFFF
[..] -> 128MB RAM
0x80000000
```

`__pa` calls `__virt_to_phys` -> `__pv_stub` which I do not unterstand.

```
static inline phys_addr_t __virt_to_phys(unsigned long x)
{
    phys_addr_t t;

    if (sizeof(phys_addr_t) == 4) {
        __pv_stub(x, t, "add", __PV_BITS_31_24);
    } else {
        __pv_stub_mov_hi(t);
        __pv_add_carry_stub(x, t);
    }
    return t;
}
```

Where is the beginning of the virtual address space defined? How does `__pv_stub` work? Why does __pa return an invalid address?

Comment: You need to use DMA mapping API instead of your custom stuff. Just call `dma_map_single()` (if the size is one page), for example, and use that *bus* address (note the difference between *physical* address and *bus* address).

Answer (score 1):

Pleae refers to https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/physical-address-on-a-x86-64-bit-machine-914781-print/ , it may be helpful to you.

Part of the kernel virtual address space in Linux is a contiguous mapping of physical memory. If you use the __pa macro on a virtual address in that range you get the corresponding physical address. But are the page tables in that range or what does __pa do if you use it in some other range? I don't know.